# Styling the width of tables cells

Tags: html, css

I have a problem choosing the table cells.

I defined my table cells to have the following measurements:

```
 cell 1: 220px
 cell 2: 315px
 cell 3: 265px
 cell 4: 200px
 Adds to 1000px
```

The measurements that I get when opening the table in a browser:

```
     cell 1: 190px
     cell 2: 264px
     cell 3: 222px
     cell 4: 168px
     Adds to 844px
```

Note that I dont set the width of the table. I also have no other elements on the page apart from that table. Why does that happen?

Comment: Did you remove all padding, borders, and cell spacing?

Comment: You need to show your HTML/CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <style type="text/css" media="screen">
         table { border-collapse: collapse; table-layout: fixed }
         td { padding: 0; border: 1px solid black }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table>
         <col width="220" />
         <col width="315" />
         <col width="265" />
         <col width="200" />
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td>col 1</td>
               <td>col 2</td>
               <td>col 3</td>
               <td>col 4</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

`col` is legal element used to [layout the table cells](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.4.2).

In the above examples Firebug will show the cells' width with the desired size in pixels minus 1px for borders (which will collapse). The entire table will be exactly 1000px wide.

Comment: true. in FF it works..but in chrome it shows smaller measurements

Answer (score 0):

We really need more code to asses this. Please create a demo js-fiddle.

Did you use the style-rule: `table-layout:fixed; border-collapse: collapse;` on the table itself, together with the attributes: `border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"`?
Did you also set the intended total table width of 1000px?

Comment: Do the table cells have any content yet?

Answer (score 0):

Set the width of your table, ad you'll get the correct result.

[See this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/PhDTw/)

Comment: setting the table width didnt help

Comment: @GitaarLAB Please check the fiddles and answers before commenting.

Comment: @Alex Thomas: Darn it, you are completely right. Please accept my apology, I'll even UP-vote your answer! Had to make a serious error someday.. Truly sorry! I can also remove my comments to this answer to keep it clean for the future! Then I'll be off to bed, having learned answering questions for more tan 24 hours straight is a not a good idea haha.